# Differential Equations: Initial Value Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$y = -t\cos t - t $ is a solution of the initial value problem:  $$t\frac{dy}{dt} = y + t^2\sin t$$
where $$y(\pi) = 0$$

I know how to find out if $y$ is a solution, but I'm not sure how to do it when $y(\pi) = 0$.

Comment: Proper notation is $t\cos t$, coded in MathJax as t\cos t, not $t cos t$. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @Ramaion: Well, we have as the solution $y(t) = -t \cos t + c t, y(\pi) = 0 \implies c = -1$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks!

Comment: @Moo Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have verified that the given equation is a solution to the differential equation, it just remains to check that $y(\pi)=0$.

$$
y(\pi)=-\pi\cos(\pi)-\pi=\pi-\pi=0
$$
Indeed, the solution given satisfies the boundary conditions and  is solution to the IVP.

Comment: Thanks! Is this the standard way of approaching the problem, or is there another way?

Comment: It is the standard way. Note that you could have checked any other solution which differed from the one given by a constant, i.e. $y+c$. To remove this constant, you use the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

$$y(\pi)=-\pi\cos(\pi)-\pi=\pi-\pi=0$$ is the required solution

Answer (score 0):

The $y(\pi)$ shouldn't matter if you know already how to do it without the initial value. For the given y we see that $y(\pi)$ is equal to 0 so now just plug in $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}$ and prove that it works out

Comment: Why should the $y(\pi)$ not matter? OP may not realize that $-t\cos t-t+100=y$ is not a solution, and your answer will not help them see this.